# RFC for "Received: With ESMTPS"

Tags: smtp, smtps

Email `Received:` headers often say "With ESMTPS" but this phrase seems to have no standard describing it.

is there an RFC for `Protocol` `ESMTPS`?

[RFC5321](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5321.txt) only lists `SMTP` and `ESMTP`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about [RFC3848](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3848)

> Abstract

> This registers seven new mail transmission types (ESMTPA, ESMTPS,
> ESMTPSA, LMTP, LMTPA, LMTPS, LMTPSA) for use in the "with" clause of
> a Received header in an Internet message.
> ...
> The new keyword "ESMTPS" indicates the use of ESMTP when STARTTLS
> is also successfully negotiated to provide a strong transport
> encryption layer.